# How to set a on_message to stop working after x time (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code looks like this:

```
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
  if "hi" in message.content.lower():
    await message.channel.send("yes or no")
    @bot.listen()
    async def on_message(message):
      if "yes" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("said yes")
      elif "no" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("said no")
```

Once the user says hi, if they say yes, it will always say "said yes" and the same with "said no". I want it to only say "said yes" if you said hi previously and once answered end the second `on_message()` so that if you say yes it does not answer again. Otherwise, if the user did not answered in 5 seconds, the `on_message` ends automatically

is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
You're probably looking for [bot.wait_for()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

```py
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author
    
    await ctx.send('Yes or no')
    resp = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=5.0) # timeout in seconds

    if 'yes' in resp.content.lower():
        await ctx.send('Said yes')
    elif 'no' in resp.content.lower():
        await ctx.send('Said no')
```

Comment: Thanks!! It was really useful!